# Create list of arrays that contain specific element

Tags: python, arrays

I need to create a function that searches if certain string is within an array and create a list with all the elements (lists) that contain it. For example:

```
word = 'busy'
array = [[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']],[['F27', 'Normal', [], ['free', '0'], 28016.537865230806, 'working', '1']]]
```

So my output should be:

```
[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 362.01, 'working', '1']]
```

But I only get that the validation that says that the string doesn't exist, when it obviously does. Here's the code:

```
array = [[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']],[['F27', 'Normal', [], ['free', '0'], 28016.537865230806, 'working', '1']]]

def searchBusyWorkers(array):
    busy = []
    for x in array:
        if 'busy' in x:
            ind = x.index('busy')
            busy.append(array[ind])
            return busy
        else:
            return "No workers have that condition."
```

Comment: `'busy' in x` fails because "busy" is nested one level deeper. In other words, there is no `'busy' in x` but there is a sub-array in x that contains the string "busy"

Comment: Do you expect "busy" to always occur in the fourth element within another list? Or can it be anywhere, nested at any level?

Comment: Yes, the list will always be in that order

Comment: Your "array" as your question originally stood was actually a tuple. Should it have the extra `[]` that were added around it by the edit?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```py
word = 'busy'
array = [[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']],
[['F27', 'Normal', [], ['free', '0'], 28016.537865230806, 'working', '1']]]


def searchBusyWorkers(array,word):
    out = []
    for a in array:
        for i in a:
            for x in i:
                try:
                    if word in x:
                        out.append(i)
                except TypeError:
                    if word == x:
                        out.append(i)
    if out:
        return out
    return "No workers have that condition."

print(searchBusyWorkers(array,word))
```

OUTPUT

```py
[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']]
```

Comment: As soon as it lets me ill accept it

Answer (score 4):

`'busy' in x` fails because "busy" is nested one level deeper. In other words, there is no `'busy' in x` but there is a sub-array in x that contains the string "busy".

Since you mention that 'busy' will always be at a particular index, you need to unpack to get the sub-array and then check that index -

```py
for x in array:
    elements, *_ = x
    if 'busy' in elements[3]:
        print(x)
```

output

```
[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']]
```

Comment: What if he wants to search for `'working'`. THen this code is failing.

Comment: IIUC, the primary problem was not able to find the word with the `'busy' in x` type of construct. OP also already mentioned that the word will only occur in `elements[3]`. I hope wrapping this code in a function to accept an input word is straightforward.

Comment: I think you don't read the question properly OP says _"I need to create a function that searches if certain string is within an array and create a list with all the elements (lists) that contain it.", Not only `'busy'`._

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(array)):
  for j in (array[i]):
    if isinstance(j, list):
      try:
        for r in j:
          if word in r:
            new_list.append(array[i])
      except:
        ...
    if word in j or word in array[i]: #update
         new_list.append(array[i])

print(*new_list) # Update
```

Output:

```
[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']]
```

Comment: What if he wants to search for `'working'`. THen this code is failing.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out @SharimIqbal, I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
array = [[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']],[['F27', 'Normal', [], ['free', '0'], 28016.537865230806, 'working', '1']]]

def searchforword(word, array):
    return([y for x in array for y in x for i in y if word in str(i)])
```

Results:

```
word = 'busy'
print(searchforword(word, array))
[['99', 'Normal', [], ['busy', '0'], 28016.2, 'working', '1']]
word = 'free'
print(searchforword(word, array))
[['F27', 'Normal', [], ['free', '0'], 28016.537865230806, 'working', '1']]
```